# lightswitch adding rows programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have this method to insert new conditions selected from a dropdown list. The list is multi select so you can select more than one item. If I select 4 items from the list 4 items will get inserted in the database however all the values are the same. It will take the last item selected and insert that 4 times.

e.g If I choose A B C D and I check the database it'll show up D four times. I believe it is something to do with this line of code but I am stuck on it.

```
myapp.AuditAssets.Submit_execute = function (screen) {

    var list = screen.findContentItem("Conditions");
    var selected = lsWire.getSelectedListItems(list);

    _.forEach(selected, function(item) {

        var assetcondition = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.JMSData.AssetConditions.addNew();
        assetcondition.Asset = screen.ScannedAssetsByProject.selectedItem;
        assetcondition.Condition = screen.Conditions.selectedItem;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
myapp.AuditAssets.Submit_execute = function (screen) {
    var list = screen.findContentItem("Conditions");
    var selected = lsWire.getSelectedListItems(list);

    _.forEach(selected, function(item) {
        var assetcondition = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.JMSData.AssetConditions.addNew();
        assetcondition.Asset = screen.ScannedAssetsByProject.selectedItem;
        assetcondition.Condition = item;
    });
}
```